# Discord Bot Help for gpt-3.5-turbo

Tags: discord.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I know it's not good practice to come here with 200+ lines of code looking for help, but unfortunately I've tapped out GPT-4 and it's not helping at this point (likely due to 2021 beings it's knowledge cap). While I've fed it articles trying to fix this, we're both stumped. Here's my code:

```
your textrequire('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed, ReactionCollector } = require("discord.js");
const promptsFile = 'prompts.txt';
    const cacheFile = 'conversationData.txt';
    const BOT_CHANNEL_ID = '1089681927482658930';


let prompts = fs.readFileSync(promptsFile, 'utf-8');
const qaPrompt = `You are a CEO's assistant. Your goal is to help your CEO plan his or her day, create schedules, and stay on track. You also help develop new ideas, etc.\n`;

prompts += qaPrompt;

function getConversationData() {
  let conversationData = {};

  try {
    const conversationDataStr = fs.readFileSync(cacheFile, 'utf-8');
    if (conversationDataStr) {
      conversationData = JSON.parse(conversationDataStr);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error while reading conversation data:', err);
  }

  return conversationData;
}

if (!fs.existsSync(cacheFile)) {
  fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile, '{}');
  console.log(`Created ${cacheFile}`);
}


const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MESSAGES"
  ]
})

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
  console.log(`Username: ${client.user.username}`);
  console.log(`Discriminator: ${client.user.discriminator}`);
  console.log(`Avatar: ${client.user.avatar}`);
  console.log(`User ID: ${client.user.id}`);
  console.log(`Bot: ${client.user.bot}`);
  console.log(`System: ${client.user.system}`);
  console.log(`Flags: ${client.user.flags}`);
});


client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

const PAST_MESSAGES = 8
const STATE_SPACE = 3
const THUMBS_UP = ''
const THUMBS_DOWN = ''

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.id !== BOT_CHANNEL_ID) return;

  message.channel.sendTyping();

  let messages = Array.from(await message.channel.messages.fetch({
    limit: PAST_MESSAGES,
    before: message.id
  }))
  messages = messages.map(m => m[1])
  messages.unshift(message)

  let users = [...new Set([...messages.map(m => m.member?.displayName), client.user.username])]

  let lastUser = users.pop()

  let conversationData = getConversationData();
  const channelId = message.channel.id;

  let stateSpace = '';
  for (let i = 3; i < messages.length; i += 2) {
  const userMsg = messages[i - 2];
  const botMsg = messages[i - 1];
  const prevBotMsg = messages[i - 3];

stateSpace += `${prevBotMsg.author.username}: ${prevBotMsg.content}\n`;
stateSpace += `${userMsg.author.username}: ${userMsg.content}\n`;
stateSpace += `${botMsg.author.username}: ${botMsg.content}\n`;
}



async function createCompletion(options) {
  try {
    const axios = require('axios');
const response = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`
  },
  data: {
    "model": "text-davinci-002",
    "prompt": options.messages.map(msg => `${msg.role === "assistant" ? "Assistant" : "User"}: ${msg.content}`).join('\n') + '\n',
    "temperature": 0.4,
    "max_tokens": 300,
    "top_p": 1,
    "presence_penalty": 0,
    "frequency_penalty": 0,
    "stop": "\n"
  }
});

return response.data.choices[0].text;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}



// Define the options for the createCompletion function
const options = {
  messages: messages.map(msg => ({
    role: msg.author.bot ? "assistant" : "user",
    content: msg.content
  })),
  temperature: 0.4,
  max_tokens: 300,
  top_p: 1,
  presence_penalty: 0,
  frequency_penalty: 0,
  stop: "\n"
};

const response = await createCompletion(options);


if (!response) {
  console.error('Error while creating completion');
  return;
}


console.log("API response:", response);
const truncatedResponse = (response && response.choices && response.choices.length > 0) ? response.choices[0].text.slice(0, 2000) : 'No response';



console.log("response", response.choices?.[0]?.text || 'No response')

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(response.choices?.[0]?.text || 'No response');
const botMsg = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
console.log("embed", embed);


// Add reactions for user feedback
await botMsg.react('');
await botMsg.react('');

// Create filter for collector
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

console.log("botMsg", botMsg);


// Create collector to wait for user feedback
const collector = botMsg.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 60000, max: 1 });

collector.on('collect', async (reaction) => {
let userFeedback = '';
if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
  userFeedback = 'positive';
} else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
  userFeedback = 'negative';
}

// Update conversation data with user feedback
if (!conversationData[channelId]) {
  conversationData[channelId] = [];
}
conversationData[channelId].push({
  author: message.author.username,
  content: userFeedback
});

// Save conversation data to file
fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile, JSON.stringify(conversationData));
console.log(`The conversation data for channel ${channelId} has been cached.`);

// If user gives negative feedback, ask for clarification
if (userFeedback === 'negative') {
  const followUpEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("I'm sorry to hear that. Could you please provide more information on what I can do better?");
  await message.channel.send({ embeds: [followUpEmbed] });
}

});

collector.on('end', async (collected) => {
// If no feedback is collected, assume neutral feedback
if (collected.size === 0) {
// Update conversation data with neutral feedback
if (!conversationData[channelId]) {
conversationData[channelId] = [];
}
conversationData[channelId].push({

  author: message.author.username,
  content: message.content
  });
  
  // Save conversation data to file
  fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile, JSON.stringify(conversationData));
  console.log(`The conversation data for channel ${channelId} has been cached.`);

  // Update conversation data with the latest message
  if (!conversationData[channelId]) {
    conversationData[channelId] = [];
  }
  conversationData[channelId].push({
    author: message.author.username,
    content: message.content
  });

  // Save conversation data to file
  fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile, JSON.stringify(conversationData));
  console.log(`The conversation data for channel ${channelId} has been cached.`);
}})});
```

Here's my error:

```
PS C:\Users\AJBEATX\Desktop\GPT-3-discord-chatbot-backupmain> node index.js
Logged in as [SDO] Assistant#3551
Username: [SDO] Assistant
Discriminator: 3551
Avatar: 87ac387bc9fb8a963f90b4260f7e711d
User ID: 1077722654288658442
Bot: true
System: false
Flags: [object Object]
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
    at settle (C:\Users\AJBEATX\Desktop\GPT-3-discord-chatbot-backupmain\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:1900:12)       
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\AJBEATX\Desktop\GPT-3-discord-chatbot-backupmain\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2952:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer 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',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.3.4',
      'Content-Length': '342',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat',
    data: '{"model":"text-davinci-002","prompt":"User: Hey there\\nUser: Hello assistant\\nUser: Hello?\\nUser: Hello assistant, how are you?\\nUser: Hello assist\\nUser: Good evening assistant. How are you today?\\nUser: Hello?\\nUser: Hello?\\nAssistant: \\n","temperature":0.4,"max_tokens":300,"top_p":1,"presence_penalty":0,"frequency_penalty":0,"stop":"\\n"}'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: '342',
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.openai.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.openai.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 188,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /v1/chat HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer 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\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 342\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/v1/chat',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 404,
      statusMessage: 'NOT FOUND',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 18,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.openai.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 342,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'NOT FOUND',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      date: 'Tue, 28 Mar 2023 18:00:05 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '140',
      connection: 'close',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'openai-version': '2020-10-01',
      'x-request-id': '1bde8165caa0c3e9cb191ef3b4d4db95',
      'openai-processing-ms': '4',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat',
      data: '{"model":"text-davinci-002","prompt":"User: Hey there\\nUser: Hello assistant\\nUser: Hello?\\nUser: Hello assistant, how are you?\\nUser: Hello assist\\nUser: Good evening assistant. How are you today?\\nUser: Hello?\\nUser: Hello?\\nAssistant: \\n","temperature":0.4,"max_tokens":300,"top_p":1,"presence_penalty":0,"frequency_penalty":0,"stop":"\\n"}'
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: '342',
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /v1/chat HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer 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\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 342\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/v1/chat',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.openai.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: { error: [Object] }
  }
}
Error while creating completion
```

ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED!!!

I tried a few things, mainly switching between Axios and OpenAI's npm (node?) (I'm new, apologies). Unfortunately GPT has told me I have to use Axios to get a response at this point, since I'm using gpt-3.5-turbo

The goal is obviously just making a discord bot that responds to users using turbo. I also want to include learning, hence the reaction thumbs up or thumbs down buttons for the discord embed. Eventually I'll use GPT-4 to help finish that portion up, but for now, I just want the code working.

My environment variables are properly stored in .env, and the key and discord bot token are correct.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend reading the [API reference](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat) but there are a few main issues that I see with this code:

1. You're using a model that isn't allowed for the chat endpoint

```
{
    "model": "text-davinci-002", // <-- this is an invalid model
    "prompt": options.messages.map(msg => `${msg.role === "assistant" ? "Assistant" : "User"}: ${msg.content}`).join('\n') + '\n',
    "temperature": 0.4,
    "max_tokens": 300,
    "top_p": 1,
    "presence_penalty": 0,
    "frequency_penalty": 0,
    "stop": "\n"
  }
```

You should be using `"gpt-3.5-turbo"` instead.

2. The endpoint you're using is wrong.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat
```

should be

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

3. The chat endpoint doesn't use a prompt, it uses messages

```
{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": options.messages, // <-- change your code to look like this
    "temperature": 0.4,
    "max_tokens": 300,
    "top_p": 1,
    "presence_penalty": 0,
    "frequency_penalty": 0,
    "stop": "\n"
  }
```